# Spring security grails plugin

Tags: spring, grails

I'm using [Spring security grails plugin v2.0.0 RC5](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core?skipRedirect=true) in my grails application , but i noticed something , that while login to the application the username is not case sensitive for instance if you wrote `user` or `USER` both will login successfully. What i need to do is to make the username case sensitive.

i  found the that `isLoggedIn` action in `springSecurityService` handling the login but i can't see anything in it any checking of the provided username or password.

here is the `isLoggedIn` code :

```
boolean isLoggedIn() {
    def authentication = SCH.context.authentication
    authentication && !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)
}
```

Am i searching the the right place ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration property for that. https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#domainClassProperties

`userLookup.usernameIgnoreCase`

Comment: i added `grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernameIgnoreCase=true` to my `config` file but still getting the same results.

Comment: Then perhaps your database is ignoring case? Try executing queries directly against your database with mixed case to test

Comment: your right the DB retrieves the row if i wrote `username='USER'` or `username='user'`, how to prevent this in grails or the DB?

Comment: I found a way for doing this as my DB is `MYSQL` , to make the collation of the DB `utf8_bin` , is there a way in Grails to define the collation ?

Answer (score 0):

In my Grails app I'm using the Spring Security plugin and have defined a custom userDetailsService Spring bean in order to control how user and role data is retrieved, e.g.

```
class MyUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    /**
     * Some Spring Security classes (e.g. RoleHierarchyVoter) expect at least one role, so
     * we give a user with no granted roles this one which gets past that restriction but
     * doesn't grant anything.
     */
    static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User.withTransaction { status ->

            User user = User.findByUsername(username)
            if (!user && user.username.equal(username)) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)
            }

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)}
            return new CustomUserDetails(
                    user.username,
                    user.password,
                    user.enabled,
                    !user.accountExpired,
                    !user.passwordExpired,
                    !user.accountLocked,
                    authorities ?: NO_ROLES,
                    user.id,
                    user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you will see

```
**if (!user && user.username.equal(username)) {**
```

this will solve your problem.
But here is another problem, your implementation also depends on your database because like MySQL is case insensitive, so if you search a user with name Joy then it will return all the user doesn't wich have name joy doesn't matter it is in capital letter or small letter.
So you need check in database value before persisting new user.
 also, another problem is, if you will check the user domain

```
 username blank: false, unique: true, email: true
```

username is unique, means you can't insert username joy again if Joy exists in db, so you need to change it and write your own custom logic to handle this problem.